# Getting the Date value from a 'curl HEAD command'

Tags: linux, curl

I want to check if a file located in a http svn location is produced today or not. I am running the following command to get the metadata-

```
curl -i -X HEAD http://subversion.abc.com/svn/repos/latestOutput/somsuvra.xml
```

this command is giving me all the details like Date: , Server: , Last modified date: etc. But I want to get the Date when the file is created. And then check it with the system date. If its not matching then the file is stale. Can this be done?

Comment: Post the results so we can have a look. If the last modified date is there, it can be done. Will need a bit more than just curls though ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

Get `Last-Modified` date as unix timestamp:

```
curl -s -I http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/AUTHORS | 
    awk '/Last-Modified/{ date=""; for(i=2;i<=NF;++i) date=(date " " $i); print date;}' | 
    xargs -I{} date -d {} +"%s"
```

Then get your current time as timestamp:

```
 date +"%s"
```

Then compare the two timestamps.

UPDATE:

You should really study some beginner manuals on shell scripting.
Here's your script:

```
URL="$1"

timestamp() {
    date +"%s"
}

modificationTimeStamp() {
    curl -s -I HEAD "$URL" | 
        awk '/Last-Modified/{ date=""; for(i=2;i<=NF;++i) date=(date " " $i); print date;}' | 
        xargs -I{} date -d {} +"%s"
}

t=$( timestamp )
modt=$( modificationTimeStamp )

if [ "$t" -ne "$modt" ]; then
    echo "no match"
fi
```

Comment: dekkard, I can get the two time stamps, but how can I compare the two timestamps? Can you help me with that?

Comment: Timestamps are just numbers. Use the usual bash comparison operators: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

Comment: I am writing a script like this, but its not working

Comment: URL=$1
echo $URL
# Define a timestamp function

timestamp() {
  date +"%s"
}

modificationTimeStamp() {

curl -s -I HEAD $URL | awk '/Last-Modified/{ date=""; for(i=2;i<=NF;++i) date=(date " " $i); print date;}' | xargs -I{} date -d {} +"%s"
}

timestamp
modificationTimeStamp

if [timestamp ne modificationTimeStamp]; then
echo "no match"
fi